# Android FTP client application- how to login into the FTP server, What FTP server can be used?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ftp

I am working in Windows 7, and I am learning to code for Android.

I need to create an FTP client to upload and download the files from free FTP servers. I am using "www.drivehq.com", which is a free ftp space. I need to know whether I can use this kind of free space as my FTP server, or if not, which FTP server can be used?

I have written the following code to login to an FTP server, as well as to upload a file. It doesnt show any errors, but I couldn't check from the emulator (android 2.2) whether the login was successful. The file is not uploaded, I separately checked through website using my login account in that FTP server.

How should I proceed further? How can I login successfully and upload the file?

```
FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
try
{
   con.connect("http://www.ftpserver.com");
   if (con.login("user name", "password"))
   {
      con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
      String data = "test data";
      ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
      boolean result = con.storeFile("/sdcard/abc.jpg", in);
      in.close();
      if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
      //lblResult.setText("Login successful.");
   }
}
 catch (Exception e)
 {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }


 try
 {
      con.logout();
      con.disconnect();
 }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
        lblResult.setText("Login successful.");
        else {
              lblResult.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
             }
         }
       });
```

---

i dont know, whether i am getting any exception.

```
    FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
    try
       {
           con.connect("FTPserver");
            if (con.login("username", "password"))
                         {
             lblResult.setText("Login successful.");  
             con.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

i  have changed

```
con.connect("http://www.ftpserver.com");
```

into

```
con.connect("ftp.ftpserver.com");
```

when i run this it prints "login successful", it means, i have logged in, isn't it? but file is not getting uploaded.

```
  String data = "test data";
  ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
  boolean result = con.storeFile("/text.txt", in);
```

what is this test data? 
"con.storefile"- inside the brackets what i need to fill? whether destination location or path of the source file need to be uploaded.

if it is the path of source file, i have my datas in the sdcard,which i have created virtually for my emulator, using DDMS perspective i loaded the files in sdcard, how can i represent the path of that file, if it is destination location, should i need to include the url of the directory?

Comment: I didn't understand your question if there are any. You say you can login and upload and then you ask "can i able to login and upload the file? what i need to do??" . Someone close this question

Comment: i tried that code to login but,i couldn't login and upload the files. while running the application i entered the username and password then it shows "the application closed unexpectedly". my objective is transfer the files from SDCard to remote FTP server, to provide the illusion that mobile user has infinite memory by utilizing free FTP servers, i thought to use  "http://www.drivehq.com". can i use this FTP server? or shall i go for someother?, if u know anything, can u suggest me.

Comment: do you get an exception?

Comment: FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
        try
           {
               con.connect("ftp.drivehq.com");
                if (con.login("sasikala.viji1987", "viji.sasi"))
                          {
               lblResult.setText("Login successful.");

Comment: please view my updated question...

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html.

It says:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://user01:pass1234@ftp.foo.com/README.txt;type=i");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream(); // To download
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload
```

Comment: thank you... i login into the FTP Server and uploaded my file, i used different code,  [http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=28] this code is very usefull....